# Fully automated Jenkins docker setup with agent

Tags: docker, jenkins

Is it possible to get a **fully automated** docker setup for Jenkins and a build agent locally (just a playground)?

I've looked on and off for a while and not managed to succeed getting this up and running.  There have been countless blog posts and a lot of manual intervention.  There have been a number of docker images for the agent - [some of which have been deprecated over time](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/slave/).

All I want to do is run a `docker compose up` to get my Jenkins and agent working - to setup a build and kick it off manually on the agent from the admin web front end.

### Starting over

The following yaml creates the Jenkins container and allows me to login with the admin user.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - "20010:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins/admin/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
      - JENKINS_ADMIN_ID=admin
      - JENKINS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    restart: always

  jenkins-build-agent:
    image: jenkins/agent
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
```

I did look at using the CASC approach a while ago to no avail - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-jenkins-setup-with-docker-and-jenkins-configuration-as-code.

There are a number of different agent images available - but not sure as yet which is the best one to suit my needs:

1. jenkins/agent (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/agent/)
2. jenkins/ssh-agent (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/ssh-agent)
3. jenkins/slave (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/slave)
4. jenkins/ssh-slave (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/ssh-slave)
5. docker-inbound-agent (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/inbound-agent/)

Ideally I want to know what options I have to achieve this.  Any high level steps required to do this and what docker image to use for the build agent.  Examples would be great.